# Linear algebra module

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, template

I'm working on a linear algebra module to improve my knowledge with mathematics and, because I'll need a lightweight linear algebra module for my future work with Vulkan!

I tried to keep a blas-like routine style, for exemple, the related functions are called like this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
Matrix<T, N, M> transposed(const DenseBase<T, M, N>& mat)
```

The whole module is templated and works with compile-time size matrices. I use an `std::vector` as a storage container because I want to keep it allocated on the heap (for large matrices)

The 2nd goal is to provide an access to row/column element by reference, for example:

```
Matrix<float, 10, 10> matrix{};
matrix.col(1)[1] = 5; // 2nd element of 2nd matrix's column is now set to 5
```

To achieve this, I have a hierarchy with a base class:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
class DenseBase
{
 public:
 using Matrixbase = Matrix<T, M, N>;
 using Row = Rowview<DenseBase, T, N>;
 using Col = Colview<DenseBase, T, M>;

 using ConstRow = const Rowview<const DenseBase, const T, N>;
 using ConstCol = const Colview<const DenseBase, const T, M>;

  Row row(std::size_t index) { return Row{*this, index}; }
  Col col(std::size_t index) { return Col{*this, index}; }

  ConstRow row(std::size_t index) const { return ConstRow{*this, index}; }
  ConstCol col(std::size_t index) const { return ConstCol{*this, index}; }
  T& operator()(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) { return coeff(row, col); }
  T& operator[](std::size_t index) { return coeff(index); }

  const T& operator()(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) const { return coeff(row, col); }
  const T& operator[](std::size_t index) const { return coeff(index); }

  virtual T& coeff(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) = 0;
  virtual const T& coeff(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) const = 0;

  virtual T& coeff(std::size_t index) = 0;
  virtual const T& coeff(std::size_t index) const = 0;
};
```

Then, I have a `Rowview`, `Colview` class which takes a `Densebase` as an argument and implements the `coeff` functions:

```
template <typename Parent, typename T, std::size_t N>
class Rowview : public DenseBase<T, 1, N>
{
 public:
  Rowview(Parent& parent, std::size_t row) : parent_{parent}, row_{row} {}

  T& coeff(std::size_t, std::size_t col) { return parent_(row_, col); }
  T& coeff(std::size_t index) { return parent_(row_, index); }

  const T& coeff(std::size_t, std::size_t col) const { return parent_(row_, col); }
  const T& coeff(std::size_t index) const { return parent_(row_, index); }

 private:
  Parent& parent_;
  std::size_t row_;
};
```

And finally, the matrix class itself, with the `std::vector` and the implementation of `coeff` methods to access its elements.

I really need some advice, maybe some ideas about how to improve the architecture. I don't like the idea of an abstract template class, but I have no alternatives yet.

Note that you can find the whole code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Raakz/Imagine/tree/784d65715d58e4e228912ac74f40e9935c8efa39/src/imagine/math/alg).

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using matrices, I don't think that you need the runtime polymorphic behaviour offered by `virtual` but that you created `virtual` functions so that you could call methods of the derived class from methods of the base class. If this is the case, you could use static polymorphism instead, thanks to the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) idiom (CRTP).

In other words, make `DenseBase` take a `Derived` template parameter which corresponds to the type of the derived class:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N, typename Derived>
class DenseBase
{
    // ...
}
```

Then make the derived classes feed their own type to this template parameter:

```
template <typename Parent, typename T, std::size_t N>
class Rowview : public DenseBase<T, 1, N, Rowview<Parent, T, N>>
{
    // ...
}
```

Now, add a couple of methods to `DenseBase` to make a downcast when needed. Since you know the derived type at compile time thanks to the template parameter `Derived`, you can make a safe downcast with a `static_cast`:

```
Derived& derived() { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this); }
const Derived& derived() const { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this); }
```

Now you can rewrite the `coeff` methods in `DenseBase` so that they don't need to use `virtual` anymore to call the `coeff` methods from the derived class:

```
T& coeff(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) { return derived().coeff(row, col); }
const T& coeff(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) const { return derived().coeff(row, col); }

T& coeff(std::size_t index) { return derived().coeff(index); }
const T& coeff(std::size_t index) const { return derived().coeff(index); }
```

That way, you have some of the benefits of polymorphism without having to pay the cost of runtime polymorphism which I feel you won't need for such a class. That's a little bit tricky to understand and use at first, but it has clear benefits.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time. I've already heard about the CRTP pattern and tried an implementation. The problem is when I implements my BLAS functions, they needs another "Derived" template parameter? Which itself is a template type..
Can you edit your post with a BLAS function prototype if you have an idea of how to achieve it? 
Btw, isnt it too much templates parameters?

Comment: @Raakz I never had a looked at how BLAS was implemented, so I'm afraid that I can't help you much with this; I thought that it was implemented with expression templates, which is a far more complicated mechanism. You typically need one additional template parameter, but only for classes users shouldn't know about.

Comment: I mean a prototype for the same transposed function I posted on my question.
What do you mean by implemented with expression templates?

Comment: @Raakz Templates are used to produce an expression tree at compile time where each type represents an operation (`MatrixAdd<>`, `MatrixMul<>`, etc...) and there are subtle casts and conversion operators everywhere. It helps to use very efficient operations but is horrible to understand if you don't know the idiom. That's expression templates for you. You should read more about it, it's really interesting :)

Comment: @Raakz Concerning your `transpose` function, it should indeed take another template parameter from what I can see.

Comment: Thanks for the informations, I'll read about expression template as soon as possible, it seems promising! Would it replace my BLAS-like function type, then no more concerns about the actual transpose function.
If you have time i'd love an example of expression templates in my case!

Comment: @Raakz I realize that I never gave you a proper answer. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) is rather decent. Generally speaking, Google will help you find good examples more than me, and you'll probably have to read several articles before actually grasping what's going on.